# Multilinear Mappings

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, banach-spaces, multilinear-algebra

Let $E$, $F$ complex Banach spaces and $p,q\in \mathbb{N}$ with $p+q\geq 1$. I will denote by $\mathcal{L}_a(^{p,q}E;F)$ the subspace of all $(p+q)$-linear mappings $A\in \mathcal{L}_a(^{p+q}E_\mathbb{R};F_\mathbb{R})$ such that:

$$
A(\lambda x_1, \ldots,\lambda x_{p+q}) = \lambda^p \overline{\lambda}^qA(x_1,\ldots,x_{p+q})$$

for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_{p+q}\in E$

I am having problems to prove the following assertion:

> If $j\neq k$, then $\mathcal{L}_a(^{m-j,j}E;F) \bigcap
>  \mathcal{L}_a(^{m-k,k}E;F)=\{0\}$

I tried the following. Given $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$, we have:
$$A(\lambda x_1,\ldots,\lambda x_m) =
\lambda^{m-j}\overline{\lambda}^{j}A(x_1,\ldots,x_m)=
\lambda^{m-k}\overline{\lambda}^{k}A(x_1,\ldots,x_m) $$

without loss of generality, $j<k$. Hence:

$$\lambda^{m-k}\overline{\lambda}^j (\lambda^{k-j} - \overline{\lambda}^{k-j})A(x_1,\ldots,x_m)=0$$

I couldn't find an scalar that makes me conclude $A(x_1,\ldots,x_m)=0$.

Comment: did you try $m=1$, $j+k=1$?

Comment: i am only considering the case $m>1$. Actually I'm having problems to write the general case =/

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Just pick $\lambda$ so that $\lambda^{k-j}-\overline{\lambda}^{k-j}\neq 0$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I was having trouble to find such a $\lambda$, @OscarCunningham. Now the question is over :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A(\lambda x_1,\ldots,\lambda x_m) = \lambda^{m-j}\overline{\lambda}^jA(x_1,\ldots,x_m)= \lambda^{m-k}\overline{\lambda}^k A(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$

From the above, since $\lambda \neq 0$, we have:

$$\left[ \left(\frac{\lambda}{\overline{\lambda}}\right)^{k-j} - 1\right] A(x_1,\ldots,x_m) = 0$$

Thus: $\left[ \left(\frac{\lambda}{|\lambda|}\right)^{2(k-j)} - 1\right] A(x_1,\ldots,x_m) = 0$

Then, writing $\lambda = |\lambda|e^{i\phi}$ and choosing $|\lambda|=1$ and $\phi = \frac{\pi}{4(k-j)}$, we have:

$$(i-1)A(x_1,\ldots,x_m) = 0$$

Hence, $A(x_1,\ldots,x_m)=0$ for all $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ and $A=0$.